How to flatten a set, but only 1-level deep?
I use Terraform on AWS. I've got a set of database resources. Now I want to iterate over them to add them to a dashboard with a few different metrics. The initial code looks like below:
{
  "type" : "metric",
  "x" : 0,
  "y" : 0,
  "width" : 6,
  "height" : 6,
  "properties" : {
    "view" : "timeSeries",
    "stacked" : false,
    "metrics" : [
      for key, instance in databaseInstances : [
        ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsInserted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", key],
        ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsUpdated", "DBInstanceIdentifier", key],
        ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsDeleted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", key]
      ]
    ],
    "region" : "eu-west-2"
  }
}

The above is going to generate a value of the metrics as following:
[
  [
    ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsInserted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-1"],
    ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsUpdated", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-1"],
    ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsDeleted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-1"]
  ],
  [
    ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsInserted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-2"],
    ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsUpdated", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-2"],
    ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsDeleted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-2"]
  ]
]

But what I actually need is:
[
  ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsInserted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-1"],
  ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsUpdated", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-1"],
  ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsDeleted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-1"],
  ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsInserted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-2"],
  ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsUpdated", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-2"],
  ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsDeleted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "key-2"]
]

I tried many different ways using available functions, like flatten, compact, concat, setunion, etc, but couldn't achieve the result I need.
Is there an easy way of achieving that "in place", without generating additional variables outside of the metric definition?
Thanks in advance!

Looks like I'll answer my own question.
To solve the problem one can use function arguments expansion syntax (...) and concat() function like this: concat(list...).
The solution implemented in the code from above:
{
  "type" : "metric",
  "x" : 0,
  "y" : 0,
  "width" : 6,
  "height" : 6,
  "properties" : {
    "view" : "timeSeries",
    "stacked" : false,
    "metrics" : concat([
      for key, instance in databaseInstances : [
        ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsInserted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", key],
        ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsUpdated", "DBInstanceIdentifier", key],
        ["AWS/DocDB", "DocumentsDeleted", "DBInstanceIdentifier", key]
      ]
    ]...),
    "region" : "eu-west-2"
  }
}

Resources:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/concat


Thanks for coming back to drop an answer. This really saved me so much time.

I was struggling with this exact same use case!
